# How to have 2 colors in a ion-select-option label

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

I'm using a typical `ion-select` component and I want to have the label of each `ion-select-option` to use 2 colors.

The label is something like this : Main (details)
So I want the "Main" part to be one color and the "(details)" part to be another.

I'm trying to achieve it using a `span` element but it seems that the `span` disappears at runtime.

```
<ion-select (ionChange)="onPresetChange($event)" value="main">
      <ion-select-option value="main">
            Main <span class="details-style">(details)</span>
      </ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

Any thoughts on how this can be done?

Ionic version is 5 and Angular version is 11

Answer (score 0):

To achieve it you can use [Ionic CSS Shadow Parts](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-shadow-parts). It allows to style CSS properties on an element inside of a Shadow DOM components.

```
ion-select::part(placeholder) {
   color: blue;
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: I can see that there's a text part but I don't see how I can apply two colors to this part if there's no way to have different elements for the two texts.